How to compare a specific string from an array of strings
Hey I am trying to learn C and just learned about array of strings
I have been tinkering around and wrote this code
char names[1][5];
strcpy(names[1], "Welp");
if (names[1] == "Welp") {
    printf("alright works\n");
}

But it doesn't seem to work
Even after trying to figure if they are of different data types but no they both came up as pointers to char
Is there any way I can compare these two
Any help would be really appriciated

Arrays start with index 0 in C. You need to study arrays before you study strings.

The issue with your code lies in two main areas: indexing and copying strings, and how you're comparing them.
Indexing out of bounds:
    In your code you declared an array char names[1][5]; which can hold only one string of up to 4 characters (plus the null terminator). However, you are trying to access names[1]. This is out of bounds since your array can only have names[0].

String comparison:
    In C, you cannot compare strings using the == operator because it compares the memory addresses (pointers) rather than the actual content of the strings.

How you can correct your code:
Here's how you can fix these issues:
Correcting the array declaration:
    If you want to store multiple strings, make sure the first dimension matches the number of strings. For example, if you want to store two strings, you can declare char names[2][5];.

for String copying use strcpy() correctly within the bounds of your array.
for String comparison use strcmp() to compare the content of two strings.
I would recommend you to read on how Arrays work since this can happen with any value type.

OH yea that makes sense comparing addresses would be pointless, I'll fix it and report back

Alright it's working fine now, really thanks for helping out!

@SarthakHingankar A well warning enabled compiler may even warn about strcpy(names[1], "Welp"); (writing outside valid range).  Save time, enable all compiler warnings.
